# Creating columns of data in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multiple-columns

I need to create columns of data in one of my for loops. Basically, you can see that I loop through 24 angles and 5 energies. At the end I get a long single column of data. Is there a way to get 24 columns of data in an array that corresponds to the 24 angles? Here is my code:

```
# Import OVITO modules.
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.modifiers import *

# Import NumPy module.
import numpy
import sys

f=open("1.out",'w')
sys.stdout = f
with open("1.out",'w') as f:
    for i in range(1,24):
        for j in range(1,5):
            node = import_file("../Angle{}/{}eV/cascade.dump".format(i,j),multiple_frames = True)
            ovito.dataset.anim.current_frame = 1
            mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
            mod.reference.load("../../position_perfect_300.dump")
            node.modifiers.append(mod)
            node.compute()
            node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'ParticleType==1 && Occupancy.1==0 && Occupancy.2==0'))
            node.compute()
            f.write("Number of O vacant sites: %i\n" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))

f.close()
```

Comment: Not related, but to redirect standard out you should use `contextlib.redirect_stdou`. Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

Comment: @jackson-hart, is your concern some data structure or what is written on stdout?

Comment: @das-g It writes out everything I need in 1 long column, I was just wondering if I could write out everything in 24 columns. Starts at Angle1 data in column1, when loop gets to Angle2, it begins a new column, separated by a space, from the first column, and so on. It'll just make the data easier to work with.

Comment: alternatively, instead of the columns thing, I just write to 24 different files.

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question and consider whether you can boil down your code to just the parts that are relevant to your question. (The use of `ovito` is probably unrelated to how you want your output to look.) See the how to create a [mcve].